# Got 'IndexSizeError' with IE 11/Edge on large images with Openseadragon

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html5-canvas, microsoft-edge, openseadragon

I am using Openseadragon to display large images, and with some of them I got "SCRIPT5022: IndexSizeError" error message with IE 11 and Edge.

It work with small image (1024 x 656 pixels), but fails with any larger image (2981 x 4123 for example). Any other browser works fine in all cases.

I am using 'legacy-image-pyramid' type source.

My Openseadragon configuration :

```
viewer = OpenSeadragon({
id:                   'openseadragon',
toolbar:              'viewer-toolbar',
maxZoomLevel:         5,
minZoomLevel:         0,
preload:              true,
sequenceMode:         false,
tileSources:          SOURCE,
crossOriginPolicy:    'Anonymous',
// buttons
zoomInButton:         'zoom-in',
zoomOutButton:        'zoom-out',
showRotationControl:  true,
rotateLeftButton:     'rotate-left',
rotateRightButton:    'rotate-right',
homeButton:           'home',
showFullPageControl:  false,
rotateleftButton:     'rotate-left',
rotaterightButton:    'rotate-right',
// gestures
gestureSettingsMouse:   {
  clickToZoom:        false,
  dblClickToZoom:     true,
  pinchToZoom:        true,
  pinchRotate:        true
},
gestureSettingsTouch: { pinchRotate: true }
});
```

Source code of larges images (fail) :

```
var SOURCE = [
    {
      type: 'legacy-image-pyramid',
      levels: [{
        url: 'https://rgw.atolcd.com/swift/v1/sillon_container_test/entrepot/B574636101_Prev36_18930411_0001.jpg',
        height: 4123,
        width: 2981
      }]
    }
];
```

Source code of smaller image (work) :

```
var SOURCE = [
    {
      type: 'legacy-image-pyramid',
      levels: [{
        url: 'https://rgw.atolcd.com/swift/v1/sillon_container_test/entrepot/carte1.jpg',
        height: 656,
        width: 1024
      }]
    },
  ];
```

I found this issue ( https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/16192680/ and [IndexSizeError on drawImage on IE and Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914128/indexsizeerror-on-drawimage-on-ie-and-edge?rq=1) with IE11/Edge (get fixed in recent version of Edge apparently) if drawImage parameters are wrong, but OpenSeadragon's values are good. (and works with small images, so it should work with any image ?).

I tried another source type (image tile source), but same error.

It works if I disable canvas and use img instead (with useCanvas: false in Options), but this is not a solution for me (it breaks my viewer implementation).

Comment: This looks like it might be related to https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/1069 though maybe not quite the same thing. I assume you're using the latest version of OSD? Here's another related issue, but it got merged a long time ago: https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/1033 .

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I have upgraded to OSD 2.4.0 and the issue was fixed. Problem solved !

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for letting me know :)